# SystemSounds.Beep.Play not making any sound

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I am having trouble with **System.SystemSounds.Beep.[Play()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsound.play.aspx)** not making any sound for a particular user.  It seems to be working for everyone else (a fairly large user base with generally 24/7 use) but simply does not make any sound for a particular user.

What I would like to know is if this method has any particular idiosyncrasies that I should be aware of, particularly if they could cause this issue (but really even if they couldn't too)?  Has anyone else run into something like this that might point to this being a non-programming issue?

**Some extra info that might help:** *(or might be more confusing)*

- It does not appear to be a corrupt .NET install because it appears for a particular user across machines.
- The user is using the same Active Directory profile for all these machines when they have the issue
- Another user can log into the machine and use the exact same executables to get sound successfully
- The particular location where the user is has **Windows XP** machines, though not all users do (some use Windows 7)

Comment: The number of ways an audio driver and sound card can misbehave are too numerous.  It isn't on topic here either.  Ditch the machine and use another one, it isn't worth your time or ours.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check this link:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/turn-off-the-annoying-windows-xp-system-beeps/

make sure that the beep sound is not disabled for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Are the system beeps still on his computer? check C:\Windows\Media, because `Beep.Play();` should work fine.

Some other possible problems just to be sure:

- The speaker volume isn't at 0%?
- The speakers are installed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check Windows Control Panel - Sound

Sound event reference must to be set.

For example:

default beep -> Windows Background.wav